# What is the charCodeAt() equivalent in C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

What is the charCodeAt() equivalent in C#?

#### Current Code:

```
   string outString="";
    for (var i = 0; i < inpString.Length; i++)
    {
    outString += inpString.charCodeAt(i).toString(); //i need to replaced charCodeAt(i) with equalent c# code
    }
```

How can i do this in C#?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try out this

```
string outString="";

for (var i = 0; i < inpString.Length; i++)

{

outString+= ((int)inpString[i]).ToString();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will return 3 the fourth character since index starts at 0.

```
    string result = "012345";
    Response.Write(result.ToCharArray()[3]); ;
```

So in your case

```
string outString="";
for (var i = 0; i < inpString.Length; i++)
{
outString += inpString.ToCharArray()[3]; //i need to replaced charCodeAt(i) with equalent c# code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the unicode character at the specified character in a string, you might want to check out [Convert.toUint16(char)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca6w8751%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [Convert.toUint32(char)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66kzw5f0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods.

```
foreach(var a in inputstring)
    Console.Write("{0} ", Convert.ToUInt16(a).ToString("X4"))
```